# Why these functions have different limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

The functions

$f(x) = \frac{\tan(x+a)-\tan(a)}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{\sin(x+a)}{x\cos(x+a)} - \frac{\sin(a)}{x\cos(a)}$ have same graphics, but different limits when $x$ tends to zero. Why does this happen?

Comment: I have an idea how to answer (and how to assure you get the true limit), but I can present it better if you show the results you're getting as both functions approach zero.

Comment: Using wxMaxima, the first one equals to 1/cos(a)^2 and the second (sin(a)^2+cos(a)^2)/cos(a)^2

Comment: $\sin(a)^2+\cos(a)^2 =1$

Comment: So long as the denominators are not $0$, it is obvious that $f(x)=g(x)$ since $\tan (\theta)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$

Comment: Thanks I haven't noticed that